# I think eclipse cannot perfectly load git project

Tags: eclipse, git, github, import

I think eclipse cannot perfectly load git project.

I sequentially executed FILE - IMPORT - GIT - Project from Git - Clone URI - Then I pasted the location from github site's project - selected my branch - selected default directory destination - import existing eclipse project.

Once I executed like above sequence, eclipse imported the project of github PERFECTLY LIKE IMPORTING a WAR FILE. 
After resetting my computer and I set the eclipse, as you see the picture, it looks like twisted:

[image]

Jsp file and java file are mixed, they are not the structure that of team had made.

How to import git like importing a WAR FILE?

Comment: What does "resetting my computer and I set the eclipse" mean?

Comment: formatting drive and reinstalling eclipse..

Comment: Looks more like the `.classpath` file that determines what's a source folder and where the output goes was lost.